# entry_id is not working

Tags: channel-entries, entryid

Just running a test and this should be working as I have an entry in my "event" channel with and id of "907"

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="event" 
    entry_id="907" 
    dynamic="no"
}

    {title}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Instead nothing is returned. If I take entry_id off, everything works fine.

Here's a screenshot of my table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1ei3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date in the screen shot says 2014?  Is it possible it's not active yet?

Comment: That was exactly it. Added show_future_entries="yes" and it works great now. Thanks!